# Creating a declaration file in TypeScript to use a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create a declaration type file in TypeScript to be able to use an old JavaScript library I'm using.

Here's the JavaScript library

**Module.js**

```
var GridManager = function(x) {
  this.foo = function () {
  }
}
```

When I need to instantiate GridManager in JavaScript I do this

```
let gridManager = new GridManager(4);
```

Now I need to create a declaration file *.d.ts* in TypeScript

**TypeScript.d.ts**

```
declare var GridManager: {
    foo(): void;
}
```

When I create a GridManager in the .ts file I get the following error

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature

**TypeScript.ts**

```
export class View {

  gridManager: GridManager;

  constructor() {
    this.gridManager = new GridManager(4);
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .d.ts file as

```
export class GridManager {
    constructor(x:Number)
}
```

foo is hidden from the scope of your class